# Margin/Padding where there shouldn't be

Tags: html, css

Web site: http://www.srstage.d19.us

```
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

works, but that is for every element

I've worked out this hacky solution:

```
#header {
margin-bottom: -30px;
margin-top: -20px;
}
```

**The problem** is there is a space at the top and under the header image.
However, all the relevant elements including body seem to have its margin & padding set to 0.
I'm not sure exactly how to fix this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#blog-title{
    margin: 0px;
}
```

or:

```
#header h1{
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Agree with Pekka, http://getfirebug.com/ is *essential*!

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help :) To accept the answer press the `tick` beneath the vote up/down buttons to the left of my answer :)

Comment: I'm just waiting for the 5 minutes to be up :) To accept the answer.

Comment: Duh forgot about that, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

It's the default padding/margin of the surrounding `h1#blog-title` element. Force both values to 0, and it should work fine.

As a side note, for the future, Firebug's "Inspect element" and [its layout view](https://web.archive.org/web/20170902000513/http://getfirebug.com:80/layout)

[image]
<sub>(source: [getfirebug.com](https://getfirebug.com/img/layout/screenLayout-edge.gif))</sub>

are the perfect tool to find stuff like this.

Comment: You both posted at the same second: http://img808.imageshack.us/img808/4853/capturerg.png I flipped a coin on random.org and Michael won. But thanks! :) I have Firebug and looked over everything I must of missed it.

Comment: @Steven you're welcome. Random.org is a nice way of flipping the coin.

Answer (score 0):

You have margin set for inside elements. They extend to their parents. Use padding when such cases occur. In your case, the h1 in the header has a margin. remove it and it's all set.